# apply method invokation for group of similar arguments

Tags: groovy

I have such facility

```
def method(a, b, c) {}

def partialMethod = this.&method.rcurry(10)

partialMethod("text", 1)
partialMethod("some text 1", 2)
partialMethod("some text 2", 3)
partialMethod("b", 3)
```

I want somehow to combine those `partialMethod` invokation into one construction with invokes that method for all the arguments (in some array or map).

How to do it?

My only idea for now

```
[ "text" : 1, "some text" : 2, "some text" : 3, "b" : 3 ].each { k, v ->
    partialMethod(k, v)
}
```

Is there other ways?

P.S I do not really care about readability though

Comment: `"some text" : 2, "some text" : 3` cannot coexist in the map :)

Comment: @dmahapatro my bad. I creared this code as reference while was writing a message and did not see it. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ 
    ["text", 1], 
    ["some text", 2], 
    ["some text", 3], 
    ["b", 3] 
].each { 
    partialMethod(*it)
}
```

Above would be a better option than using a `Map` because entries `"some text" : 2, "some text" : 3` cannot coexist.